# mongoose: findOne using mongo _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get that this can be a duplicated question. I looked up at least 10 related questions and answers, but I am still not able to find the document.

I am trying to get the document using `.findOne()`. I have the `_id` that created by MongoDB. But, I get null for every search I try.

```
await mongoose.connection.db
                    .collection('testing')
                    .findOne({ _id: req.body.test_id }, (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            res.status(400);
                        } else {
                            console.log(`whaaaaaahsidufh ${result}`);
                        }
                    });
```

I tried `_id: mongoose.Type.ObjectId(req.body.test_id)` and other possible way to search. How can I retrieve the result by using `_id` on mongoose?

Comment: Im not sure but allback function and async keyword in same statement maybe the issue

Comment: Just tried without `await` and still not working :/

Comment: Why are you not using mongoose model?

Comment: This is from another node app. Learning microservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use findById();

```
try {   

 const test = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('testing').findById(req.body.test_id);
    if (test ) {
        console.log(`whaaaaaahsidufh ${test}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`test not found`);
    }
}catch(err){
    res.status(400);
}
```

Comment: It says, `findById` is not a function. I just added unique stringID to every doc. Using that value now. seems faster